# Set a project field from a task in workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, project-server, pwa

We have a task process where a user selects one of four options (pass, no pass, conditional, hold).

[image]

Is there a way to get the result from this task and set whatever it is to a project field:

[image]

so if a user selects PASS, the project field should be set to PASS
if user selects No Pass, the project field is set to No Pass.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this by doing the following :

- Open your project workflow .
- After Start Task process ,
- Add If condition `If variable:outcome1 equals pass`
- Then add action from the above ribbon > from action list > below `Project Web App Actions` > select `Set Project field`.

[image]

- Select the field that you need to set > and select its value (Pass,No Pass)